# Moving product/categories/sales data to clean install

Tags: database

I've been experiencing some quirky behaviour in my shop (due to my lack of best practices when first starting and multiple half uninstalled plugins/themes) so would like to copy my product data/sales (from M2E Pro integration) to a clean install. What is the best way to do this?

PS I ran the DB Repair Tool and it said Added missing foreign key..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a good way with M2E pro for doing this but my suggestion would be:

1. Use the built in import/export to get the data you need between the two installations,
2. Build you own import/export process using a third party extension like [FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport),
3. Try working with the API, though I am not 100% sure if the API will provide you with all the data you need,